# What's the install location for the Microsoft Access Runtime?

Tags: windows, microsoft-access, runtime

I've seen several references online that suggest various locations for where the Access Runtime is installed - but no definitive answer that gives install locations for each version. I'm interested in versions from 2000 to the current day (the Microsoft 365 Access Runtime).

Comment: If a non standard path is used,you can e.g. query for path to 
 msaccess.exe'  using WMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's the install location for the Microsoft Access Runtime?

It depends on 2 things, 32 or 64 bit and the version number.

The default locations are:

- 32 bit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OfficeNN`
- 64 bit `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeNN`

[Click to run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/office-click-to-run-installation) versions:

- 32 bit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office NN\ClientX86`
- 64 bit `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office NN\ClientX64\Root\OfficeNN`

where `NN` is the version number:

```
Name        NN
Access 2000  9
Access 2002 10
Access 2003 11
Access 2007 12
Access 2010 14
Access 2013 15
Access 2016 16
Access 2019 16
```

Source for version numbers: [Microsoft Access - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Microsoft_Access_Runtime)

Notes:

- > The location of the full edition (or runtime) is identical. In fact you really can’t install both at once (the install of the runtime will occur, but it is a “fake” install)

  Source: [Where is access 2013 runtime installed on windows 10 - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/where-is-access-2013-runtime-installed-on-windows/0d01d2a6-76de-41f0-b958-ac967c7a394a)
- [Microsoft Office default installation folders for Windows - Appunti dalla rete](https://www.appuntidallarete.com/microsoft-office-default-installation-folders-for-windows/) confirms the locations for versions 10 though 16.

Comment: Thank you - I've also seen references to the Runtime being installed at "C:\Program Files\Access Runtime" - do you know if this path is used at all?

Comment: I suppose it is possible to override the standard install locations listed in the answer ...

Comment: @ComputerVersteher answer updated